# Mutliple MySQL queries takes a lot of time to load page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got 11 tables which I grab results from to a single page with a 50 column table. Because of the way I get the results (around 11 queries per row, 300-500 results means 300x11 queries) it takes a lifetime to load the whole page. Some of the queries can't be avoided since I need to loop them to grab individual results per row.

I first run a query to grab all available active users and then I run all these queries on each one of them to grab the extra info needed. On the queries below I basically grab the dates for 3 of the tables and the city name.

Some of the queries:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%d/%m/%Y - %H:%i') AS eventdate, event_id FROM `events` WHERE event_userid = $user_id AND event_group = 1 AND (event_type = 4 OR event_type = 5)

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(log_date, '%d/%m/%Y - %H:%i') AS logdate FROM `history` WHERE log_email = $user_email AND log_place = 1 AND log_status = 1 ORDER BY log_date DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(link_date, '%d/%m/%Y - %H:%i') AS linkdate FROM `link` WHERE link_user = $user_id AND link_status = 1

SELECT city_name FROM `cities` WHERE city_id = $user_city
```

And some of the tables:

```
event_id |     event_date      | event_userid | event_group | event_type
1        | 2019-02-18 10:57:29 |       1      |      1      |    4
2        | 2019-02-25 11:50:20 |       1      |      1      |    5
3        | 2019-03-05 12:15:38 |       3      |      2      |    3
etc


log_id |  log_email   |      log_date       | log_place | log_status
22     | asd@asd.com  | 2019-01-30 10:15:14 |     1     |     1
23     | asd2@awo.com | 2019-02-15 12:34:48 |     2     |     1
25     | owl@bong.com | 2019-03-05 17:48:35 |     1     |     1
etc


link_id | link_user | link_comp |     link_date       | link_status
3       |     1     |    55     | 2019-02-15 14:43:37 |      1
4       |     3     |    15     | 2019-02-28 18:38:16 |      1
5       |     2     |    30     | 2019-03-08 10:12:50 |      2
etc


city_id |     city_added      | city_name | city_status
11      | 2019-01-05 10:43:30 |  London   |      1
15      | 2019-01-06 10:34:13 |  Vienna   |      1
18      | 2019-01-07 10:11:41 | Las Vegas |      2
etc
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can probably [JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join) the queries. Start with something simple first, like joining the user table with one other table, and build from there.

Comment: You have to create indexes to all **relational** table **columns**

Comment: What @Roy means is that choosing the correct indexes can speed up your queries a lot, and it is easy to do. No need to change your queries! However, do not put an index on every column, but [choose them with care](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hmm by default I would always make the first ID a primary key + Index. I will look into this. Thanks

Comment: A good column to make an index for is `linkdate.link_user` in your third example query. You have a `where link_user = $user_id`, so an index there will really help.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I did add a few keys on various tables but it seems like nothing changed whatsoever :/

Comment: Don't give up on this yet. You can evaluate the efficiency of your queries with [EXPLAIN](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries). It takes a bit of digging and learning, but in the end having good indexes is certainly worth it.